# Performing Multi label text classification

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I have a text and it's class, so I have performed single text classification, but now I want to train a multi label classifier, so I tried combining sentence to form a multi label dataset, but the lstm model is overfitting, even though there was no leakage of data for the model, is there anything I can do, any augmentation?